# Using jQuery ":visible" selector on dynamic element

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to toggle the opacity of a link control by checking if the element it toggles on/off is visible or not using the ":visible" selector. I have the following markup:-

```
<div class='btns'></div>
<p class='text'>Hello world</p>
```

With this jQuery:-

```
var text = $('.text');
text.hide();
var btn = $('<a>', {
    'href': '#',
    'text': 'click me',
    'click': function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        text.slideToggle();
        var opacity = text.is(':visible').length ? 1 : .5;
        $('.btns').animate({
            'opacity': opacity
        });
    }
});

$('.btns').append(btn);
```

The first time the link is clicked the link fades to half opacity correctly, but then the opacity doesn't change on subsequent clicks. You can see this in action on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agkF7/).

Why does the ":visible" selector fail on further clicks? Is there a better approach to this?

Apologises if this has already been answered on here, but I've not been able to find an answer to my particular question.

Comment: .is() returns a boolean, so var opacity = text.is(':visible').length ? 1 : .5; should be var opacity = text.is(':visible') ? 1 : .5;

Comment: That's what I thought, but just using text.is(':visible') failed to work at all!

Comment: because the text is always visible.. you always slidetoggle before you set `opacity` - which means the text is always visible..  You will have to capture the opacity before you start slidetoggling or inside the callback of slidetoggle

Comment: @wirey thanks that's sorted it. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to test the text's property you can do this :

```
var opacity = text.css('display') == 'none' ? .5 : 1;
text.slideToggle();
```

Be sure to test **before** you start animating, because the display will never be "none" while animating.

To understand better what properties to test, I suggest you (if you use chrome), to right click on the animated text, inspect element, then watch carrefully which style parameters are being changed live when you activate the toggle.

Comment: This worked thanks. Although I stuck with checking visibility:-

var opacity = text.is(':visible') ? 1 : .5;

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to change:

```
var opacity = text.is(':visible').length ? 1 : .5;
```

to

```
var opacity = $('.btns').css('opacity')==0.5 ? 1 : 0.5;
```